# calling custom JavaScript function from codename one

Tags: javascript, codenameone, jsobject

I recently came across the JSObject and JSFuntion,  and it seemed really confusing. Can it be used to call custom JavaScript functions and return values back to my CN1 app? Or is it for some other function?. Thanks all

Answer (score 1):

Check out the javadoc package overview for that: 
https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/javascript/package-summary.html

E.g. from that page:

> The following example shows an object with a simple add() method that
>   just adds two numbers together:

```
JSObject obj = (JSObject)ctx.get("{ add : function(a,b){ return a+b;}}");
Double result = (Double)obj.call("add", 
    new Object[]{new Integer(1), new Integer(3)}
);

// Result should be 4.0
```

Comment: Can this be used in the same way to call a JavaScript API  i.e cloudinary JavaScript functions or firebase JavaScript api functions available to developers.Thanks again

Comment: Those are usually REST API's so you don't really need to access them from JS as you can call them from Codename One e.g. we already have an open source cloudinary library: https://www.codenameone.com/blog/sizing-images-just-right-with-cloudinary.html